# Custom Quick Step to search Outlook 2010 mail

Tags: search, outlook

I would like to define a custom Quick Step in Outlook 2010 which uses the From field of a selected mail message to perform a search on the current folder. How does one set this action in the Quick Step dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick steps do not support any search related tasks.